# Laravel datetime returned from database is different from records in the same database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

Long story short:

```
public function betweenDate($startDate,$startTime,$endDate,$endTime){

      return DB::table('tablice')->where([['datum', '>', $startDate." ".$startTime], ['datum', '<', $endDate." ".$endTime]])->get();

    }
```

I need to search records in database between dates, and this code works, but with one simple error. Returned date looks like this `... {"id":62667,"br_tablice":"LK493","moguce_tablice":"LK493,LK8493,LK4293,LK4J93,LK893,L8493,LKB493,","ostalo":null,"datum":"2017-03-17 19:00:14"} ...`. Returned date is `2017-03-17 19:00:14` but in database is `2017-03-17 20:00:14`, and I cant figure it out why. In `.env` I set `APP_TIMEZONE=CET`, the same as database uses. Changing timezone doesn't work, because I tried with every timezone.

Comment: Looks like the Database is set to UTC (or maybe +2 GMT?)

Comment: Checked with `SELECT @@system_time_zone;` and response is` stdClass Object ( [@@system_time_zone] => CET )`.

Comment: it must be a timezone issue just  use this to add an hour (fast fix). `strtotime($time) + 3600; // Add 1 hour`

Comment: Check the timezone in `config/app.php`

Comment: Problem is that data is ok, it searches for correct data,but somehow laravel convert it by one timezone backward. If I add +1 hour to search I will get wrong data. All in all, search works ok, if I write query in plain php without laravel, date is correct, but with laravel, date is -1. It's some laravel issue. I dont have so much experiance with laravel, and google search does not have an answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of search, I decided to change every piece of code until above is not corrected. As in comment suggested to look at `config/app.php` but there is none related to database, but looking at `config/database.php` gives the solution to my question. In database.php, there is the line `... 'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'), ...` so I changed it to +01 and voila, it works. Thanks everyone for suggestions.